# Problem when collecting results from different runs in Omnetpp

Tags: omnet++

Since version 2.X up to version 4.X I was able to successfully record scalars with my own reimplementation of cIOutputScalarManager, that allowed me to store results from ALL runs in same instances of cLongHistogram/cDoubleHistogram classes, that were internally used by my reimplementation of cIOutputScalarManager. I am using OMNeT++ for transient states analysis, therefore I need results from many different runs (in most cases 100000 runs) averaged to get required plots, however in version 5.X each run reinstantiates whole cIOutputScalarManager from scratch, therefore instead of results from ALL runs, at the end I get results only from LAST run :( How can I get back to having one and same cIOutputScalarManager for all runs rather than separate one for each run (especially when considering parallel execution of runs, which in my case does not break results because effectively I need average from them all) ?

Thank You for any ideas that will help with fixing this issue.

Comment: Could you provide [mcve] especially the implementation of `cIOutputScalarManager`?

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** have to gather statistics for all runs (and as far as I see your use-case justifies it) then you can still implement your own manager based on `cIOutputScalarManager`, but inside that object you can just delegate all work to a **static** instance of your manager. i.e. use the *singleton design pattern* and delegate all work to that single instance.